# Django: Modifying field values before they're submitted

Tags: django, django-forms

To workaround issues with Taggit, I'm trying to add quotes around values in the tag field before they're transferred into a model. This is what I have so far but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
class TagField(models.CharField):

    description = "Simplifies entering tags w/ taggit"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TagField, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    # Adds quotes to the value if there are no commas
    def to_python(self, value):
        if ',' in value:
            return value
        else:
            return '"' + value + '"'

class CaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Case
        fields = ['title', 'file', 'tags']
        labels = {
            'file': 'Link to File',
            'tags': 'Categories'
        }
        widgets = {
            'tags': TagField()
        }
```

Comment: Did my answer ever work out of you?

Answer (score 0):

You are subclassing `models.CharField`, instead you should subclass `forms.CharField`, you're specifying for widget attribute in the form but you're trying to create a form field subclass.

Comment: When I do that, I get the error: "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'TagField'"

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is you are defining a custom model field and then trying to specify it as a widget in the form. If you indeed want a custom widget, you need to actually provide a widget instance, not a model field instance.

But to get the behavior you want, instead you need to declare the field at the Model level as an instance of your custom field class.

Try something like -

```
from django.db import models

class TagField(models.CharField):
  description = "Simplifies entering tags w/ taggit"

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TagField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  # Adds quotes to the value if there are no commas
  def to_python(self, value):
    if any( x in value for x in (',', '"') ):
      return value
    else:
      return "\"%s\"" % value

class ModelWithTag(models.Model):
  tag = TagField(max_length = 100)
```

The [to_python](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.to_python) method is also called by [Model.clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean), which is called during form validation, so I think this will provide the behavior you need.

Note, I also check for the presence of a double-quote in your condition in the to_python method, otherwise the quotes will continue to "stack up" every time save() is called.